# How to use Jacoco with application that requires install and configuration to run

Tags: jacoco

I am attempting to set up Java code coverage for a fairly complex app that

- combines multiple large modules, only one of which I need to check coverage on
- uses a combination of ant and Maven for builds
- cannot be run except as an installed application on a server, with configuration
- the automated tests to be analyzed for coverage are not part of the application build and make use of API calls to the application server from a remote client

The examples given in the [jacoco documentation](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/index.html) and in the online sources I have found assume the app under test is not previously installed and the tests are unit/integration tests run as part of the build. The documentation does not cover the details of how the jacoco instrumentation is done or when the call is recorded to a particular line of code. If I use ant or maven to instrument a particular module, use that module to build the full app, install it on a server, and configure it, will my remote tests then generate the .exec file?

Any advice on how to achieve the end goal (knowing how much of our code is covered by the tests) is greatly appreciated, including better search terms than "jacoco for installed app" which as you can imagine is ... not very useful. My google-fu is humbled.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: I need to know if what I want to do is even possible. I have used jacoco for other, smaller projects so I am not completely unfamiliar with the basic configuration--also, this is for a proprietary project so I cannot post actual code.